# How to convert a point in image imrotated with loose option to a point in image imrotated with crop option in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, coordinate-systems

How to find the relation between image `imrotated` with *loose* option *Image 1* and image `imrotated` with *crop* option *Image 2* ? the angle of rotation is not necessary -45° ...

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
Im1 = imrotate(I,-45);       % bbox option sets to 'loose' by default
Im2 = imrotate(I,-45,'nearest','crop'); % bbox option sets to 'crop'
figure(1);
subplot(2,1,1), imagesc(Im1), axis image;
subplot(2,1,2), imagesc(Im2), axis image;
```

[image]

I mean if I choose a point *(x1,y1)* from *Im1* what is the **equation** of its relation with *(x2,y2)* in *Im2*  ?? I am looking for `loose2crop()` equation ?

Comment: I don't have matlab accessible now, but the second one should be exactly the center part of the first one. The original image has probably 255 pixels (?), the second one has 255*sqrt=360 pixels(?). This results in a shift of 52 or 53 pixels (mathematically 52.5, nearest interpolation is used).

Comment: I knew that they have the same center :) well just formulate this in reversible equation in answer ...

Comment: how do you know it is 52 pixels shift ?

Comment: 360-255/2=52.5, because nearest interpolation is used either 52 or 53 is picked.

Comment: and 360 ? how did you compute it ? 255* sqrt(255) = 360 ?

Comment: any way 255 = `size(Im2,1)`

Comment: 255*sqrt(2), which is the diagonal of the 255*255 square.

Comment: @Daniel I *updated* my question with a first attempt of a function `loose2crop()` to convert the coordinates from loose image to crop image following your comments. is this okey ?

Comment: by the way @Daniel , it is not necessary to have -45° of rotation it can be anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution , please feel free to check it for fun :)

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
Im1 = imrotate(I,-45); % Image imrotated with loose option
Im2 = imrotate(I,-45,'nearest','crop');% Image imrotated with crop option

% draw image 1 loose
figure(1);
subplot(2,1,1), imagesc(Im1), axis image;
drawnow; 

%%Get a point
title('Select a point'); hold on; 
[p1] = ginput;

plot (p1(1),p1(2),'k*');
drawnow;

% convert loose p1 to crop image 
p2 = loose2crop(Im1,Im2,p1)

% draw Image 2 cropped
subplot(2,1,2), imagesc(Im2), axis image, hold on;
plot (p2(1),p2(2),'r*');
drawnow;

function p2 = loose2crop(Im1, Im2, p1)

[h1,w1] = size(Im1);
[h2,w2] = size(Im2);

shift_h = (h1 - h2)/2 ;
shift_w = (w1 - w2)/2 ;

p2(1) = p1(1) - shift_h ;
p2(2) = p1(2) - shift_w ;
```